# How to access a variable variable with a name containing spaces?

Tags: php, variables, variable-variables

How does PHP handle something like this:

```
$blah = "Testing a variable"; 
$$blah = "test";
```

What would I access my dynamically declared variable?

Comment: mmk k, so something like.. $blah = str_replace(" ", "_", $blah); would work sufficiently.

Comment: $$ is one of the true evils/joys of PHP. combine with () for fun-ness! $$blah()();

Comment: `${"Testing a variable"}` works fine.

Comment: No syntax error from listed code.

Comment: @DampeS8N in what universe is this a joy?

Comment: The one where you are coding for fun on your own? It is like coding in brainfuck. Joy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo ${'Testing a variable'};`

However, you don't want to do this in practice. It makes for unmaintainable, bug-prone code.

Answer (score 9):

Everything you need to know about variable variables at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php, except for one thing: don't use them.

Comment: -1 for giving me a link to the manual, +1 for giving me some useful syntax advice.

Comment: @Stephen I know, right? The manual explains variable variables way better than most people here could.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `$blah` must contain a valid variable name.

This will tell you about variables: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but...

```
<?php 
function I_love_you()
{
    return "haha";
}

$haha = "HoHoHo";
$tom = "I_love_you";
$blah = "tom";

echo ${$$blah()};
?>
```