# Create variable names dynamically

Tags: php

I'm creating some variable names dynamically in a while loop:

```
while($count < $agendaItemsCount) {
      $tr_mcs_agendaitem_[$count]_1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_tr_mcs_agendaitem_' . $count . '_1', true );
    ++ $count
}
```

But this code is causing an unexpected string parse error. How do I write this code so that the new var gets declared with the count variable output along with the rest of the var name?

Comment: What's the good reason for not using a key-value pair in an array?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Variable Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511948/php-variable-variables)

Comment: @Incognito I have no control of the data coming back...i'm working in wordpress. Curly braces do not work....$tr_agendaitem_{$count}_1 = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'agendaitem_' . $count . '_1', true ); still produces a syntax error

Comment: @elduderino That's the perfect case for using a map of key-value pairs. The 'custom name' would be the key, and the data would be the same data. This is how PHP handles GET/POST results, since for those the variable's name won't be known beforehand.

Comment: I'm not following you. Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

So you want to create variables like `$tr_mcs_agendaitem_1_1`, `$tr_mcs_agendaitem_2_1` etc?
While I advise using an array, you can do the following:

```
$collection = array();
while($count < $agendaItemsCount) {
  $collection['tr_mcs_agendaitem_'.$count.'_1'] = 
       get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_tr_mcs_agendaitem_' . $count . '_1', true );
    ++ $count;
}
extract($collection);
```

Another solution would be to use "[variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)":

```
while($count < $agendaItemsCount) {
  $varname = 'tr_mcs_agendaitem_'.$count.'_1';
  $$varname = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_tr_mcs_agendaitem_' . $count . '_1', true );
  ++ $count;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to initialize the array: `$collection = new array();`, in case $agendaItemsCount is 0.